# Constructor Argument Forwarding through Interface

Tags: c++, reflection, c++11, metaprogramming

I'm in need of a generic way to create an instance of any type. This task needs to be performed from a non-templated object, and so I'm currently using an interface like so:

```
class Interface
{
public:
  virtual void PlacementCopy( void *data, const void *src ) const = 0;
  virtual void PlacementNew( void *data ) const = 0;
  virtual void PlacementDelete( void *data ) const = 0;
  virtual void Delete( void *data) const = 0;
  virtual void Copy( void *dest, const void *src ) const = 0;
  virtual void NewCopy( void **dest, const void *src ) const = 0;
  virtual void *New( ) const = 0;
};
```

This is all apart of a custom reflection system, and so it is used like this:

```
int *p = META( int )->Interface->New( );
*p = 10;
```

This works by creating a templated object that derives from `Interface`, which holds the type to be constructed. The `New` operator in Interface does default construction of the type:

```
template <typename T>
class Derived : public Interface
{
  virtual void *New( void ) const override
  {
    return new T( );
  }
};
```

**Problem**:
All types that are to be constructed in this manner must provide a default constructor. I would like to somehow allow arbitrary arguments to be passed to the constructor of the type in question.

I somehow need to be able to do:

```
MetaInfo *meta = META( SomeType );
SomeType *object = meta->New( arg1, arg2 );
```

Which would perhaps look something like this in implementation:

```
template <typename T>
Derived : public Interface
{
  template <typename ... Args>
  virtual void *New( Args&& ... args ) const override
  {
    new T( std::forward<Args>( args ) ... );
  }
};
```

The `MetaInfo` object is not a templated type which makes it difficult to come up with an argument forwarding solution. I cannot simply templatize the `New` method in the `Derived` class, as you cannot templatize a virtual method.

Is what I'm asking even possible without some crazy code pre-processing?

Comment: You could use a code generator or the preprocessor (most likely [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html)) to generate an insane amount of overloads for different number and types of arguments.

Comment: Haha, well I'd prefer not to do code pre-processing if possible. Not a huge fan of adding in pre-build steps if they can be avoided. It complicates the build process and adds in the potential for unforeseen code maintenance.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if your metaobject describes a class with a single constructor taking a single `int` argument, and somebody calls `meta->New("thank you", 42.0)`? Should it be a compile-time error, a run-time error, or what?

Comment: Yeah there should totally be some type checking there if possible. Ideally compile time. I'm really looking for any sort of implementation that works for now though.

Comment: What if you had a map of strings that represented the types and a void* for the data of that type. You could then cast the void* when passing it to the constructor. This _would_ require that all the types in use be known beforehand, but that's the unfortunate reality of C++.

Edit: Take a look at this [article](http://www.vollmann.com/pubs/meta/meta/meta.html)

Comment: Well, you only have one type `MetaInfo` that represents all possible types that can be created with `MetaInfo::New`. Where exactly static typechecking is supposed to fit?

Comment: Hmm yeah I don't think there's a possibility of static type-checking.

Comment: This sounds similar to `boost::any`, doesn't it? All you need is for the concrete-constructor to be a template, but the type-erasing base would still just be a single class.

Answer (score 0):

I did end up gathering together a solution with the help of some friends!

So the biggest issue was that all types to be registered within reflection required a default constructor. To get around this you can use SNIFAE to check for the existence of a default constructor.

```
struct HasDefaultCtor
{
  template <typename U>
  static int32 SFINAE( decltype( U( ) ) * );
  template <typename U>
  static int8 SFINAE( ... );

  static const bool value = sizeof( SFINAE<T>( NULL ) ) == sizeof( int32 );
};
```

Beyond this all non-default constructors would have to be registered by hand within the reflection system, or generated with a pre-build step tool. Additional SNIFAE checks can be used to type-check and make sure registered constructors actually match real constructors within the class. For actually calling the `New` operator some run-time resolution would need to occur in order to figure out what constructor is needed to matchup with the `New` call.

I hope this makes sense and ends up being useful for someone in the future.

I also made a SNIFAE check for copy constructor:

```
template <typename T>
struct HasCopyCtor
{
  static T MakeT( void );

  template <typename U>
  static int32 SFINAE( decltype( U( MakeT( ) ) ) * );
  template <typename U>
  static int8 SFINAE( ... );

  static const bool value = sizeof( SFINAE<T>( NULL ) ) == sizeof( int32 );
};
```

Comment: c++11 already has those type traits checkers (see, e.g., http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible ).

Comment: Sure but they don't have checking for more advanced things, like a specific number of arguments.